# Escalating height of list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making a scale using list items, and I want the height of each item to big bigger than the previous one.

Other than adding a class to each, I can't work a way of doing it. I've made a fiddle showing the kind of result that I want: https://jsfiddle.net/bLj6eLe7/

The code below is effectively what I want the results to be. Preferably using css but happy to go with JS if needed.

```
<ul>
    <li style="height: 10px;">1</li>
    <li style="height: 20px;">2</li>
    <li style="height: 30px;">3</li>
    <li style="height: 40px;">4</li>
    <li style="height: 50px;">5</li>
    <li style="height: 60px;">6</li>
    <li style="height: 70px;">7</li>
    <li style="height: 80px;">8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Jquery I would do this

```js
$(function(){
  $('ul li').each(function(i,v){         
     $(this).css('height',(i * 10) +10);  
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  background: blue;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is the `v` in `i,v` for?

Comment: @Aziz `v` will be the element in that iteration, you can either use `$(this)` or `v`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this jquery code:

https://jsfiddle.net/bLj6eLe7/1/

```
var init = 1;
var sum = 10;
$('ul li').each(function() {
  var newHeight = init * sum;
  $(this).height(newHeight+"px");
  init++;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how long your list will be? So yes..

Why not doing it this way?

```css
li:nth-of-type(2) {
  height:20px;
}
```

Etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure javascript way of doing it (no jQuery required).  First add an id of `myList` to your `<ul>` and add the following script at the end of the page, or on the `onLoad` event:

```
var step = 10;
var list = document.getElementById('myList');
var items = list.children;
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var height = step * (i + 1);
  items[i].style.height = height + 'px';
}
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/bLj6eLe7/3/

Answer (score 1):

You could create a SASS loop to generate the CSS rules, completely dynamic:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .scale li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    height: $i * 10px;
  }
}
```

The output would be like this:

```css
.scale li {
  background: blue;
  list-style-type: none;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.scale li:nth-child(1) {
  height: 10px;
}

.scale li:nth-child(2) {
  height: 20px;
}

.scale li:nth-child(3) {
  height: 30px;
}

.scale li:nth-child(4) {
  height: 40px;
}

.scale li:nth-child(5) {
  height: 50px;
}

.scale li:nth-child(6) {
  height: 60px;
}

.scale li:nth-child(7) {
  height: 70px;
}

.scale li:nth-child(8) {
  height: 80px;
}

.scale li:nth-child(9) {
  height: 90px;
}

.scale li:nth-child(10) {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="scale">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/9b66rvhw/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with simple JQuery script:
Here's the code:

```
(function scale(){
     var height = 10;
     $.each($("#scale").children(), function(item){
          $(this).css("height", height);
          height+=10;
          });
}());
```

and a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLj6eLe7/5/)